# Не работает вертикальная прокрутка в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня имеется разметка. ListBox генерируются, в них чуть больше элементов, чем может вместиться на экране. 
Прокрутка не работает почему-то.

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Day}"/>

                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:iDayControl/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Сделайте пример полным и не зависящим от своих контролов.

Comment: не очень понятно, почему вы используете в качестве шаблона данных для элемента коллекции (itemscontrol) другую коллекцию (listbox).

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov такова структура приложения, у меня имеется коллекция из коллекций, которую необходимо отобразить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весь код примера:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CardList}" BorderBrush="#FFCB2F2F" BorderThickness="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    </StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding WorksList}">
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind для MainWindow:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication8
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<WorkCard> CardList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> tmp = new List<string>(){"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        List<string> tmp1 = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        CardList = new List<WorkCard>()
                   {
                       new WorkCard("First", tmp),
                        new WorkCard("Second", tmp),
                         new WorkCard("Third", tmp),
                          new WorkCard("Fourth", tmp1),
                           new WorkCard("Fifth", tmp)
                   };
        DataContext = this;
    }

}

public class WorkCard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> WorksList { get; set; }

    public WorkCard (string name, List<string> list)
    {
        Name = name;
        WorksList = list;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ListView Не могу использовать по причине необходимости выбора элементов внутри визуальной коллеции (ListBox, например)

Comment: так в ListView так же есть свойство SelectedItem.

Comment: Допустим, изменил ListBox на ListView, скролл не появился (как физически, так и визуально)

Comment: Поменяйте ItemsControl на ListView и все заработает

Comment: @bodynar а если еще stackpanel в datatemplate окружите заключите в ScrollViewer, то у вас появится ползунок и для каждого отдельного списка.

Comment: @bodynar если мой совет помог вам, отметьте его как ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.

Добавил ScrollViewer, как посоветовал @Fony Fazoulyanov вокруг элемента, держащего ItemsControl.

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <LocalContr:iWeekControl/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```